# This overlay is covering the body's scrollbar

Tags: html, css

This is the overlay:

[image]

I tried giving the overlay a width property of 1100px, but I had still had problems with it.

This is my markup:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Poppins"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="interior.css">
<title>Interior Design</title>

<div id="col-md-3" class="col-md-3">
    <div class="inner sticky-top">
        <div class="closer p-3 bg-secondary text-center font-weight-bold">Close Menu</div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h3 class="firstText">Company</h3>
        </div>
        <h3 class="secondText">Name</h3>
        <div class="sidebarNav">
            <a href="#home" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Home</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#showcase" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Showcase</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#services" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Services</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#designers" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Designers</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#packages" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Packages</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact" class="text-decoration-none">
                <div class="nested-div ">Contact</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my style:

```css
.col-md-3,.apply {
    display: none;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100% ;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    /* z-index: 2000; */
    background-color: #0000009e;
    top: 100;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working [repro] for debugging details. If you use a framework also add this as a tag and a link to stylesheet it within the MCVE.

Comment: use as width: `calc(100vh - 20px)` It will not prefectly fit as scroobar width differ from browser to browser. Alternativly you could set the exact scrollbar width yourself.

Comment: Lovely, thanks for showing me, why haven't you left a question?

Comment: @CuteCode Rob who are you referring to.